# Build lambda expression (predicate) with dynamic comparison operators

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Take Northwind as example.

My goal is to use Linq to Entity to search Employees dynamically.

My expression maybe:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> exp= em => em.EmployeeID > 2;
```

Here the operator `'>'` is selected by combobox at runtime, and it may be '<', '=', '<>', 'contains' and so on.

My question is,  how to build the expression dynamically with the operator selected?

One important thing, **no selective statements allowed**, such as 'if' and 'switch'.

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted, why?

Comment: @Brad Christie, but not that one.

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus, that one is good, I will examin it first. Thanks!

Comment: @LeiYang of course, this is one of mines ;) To be honest, the comparison operators are ok, but the "contains" part is missing.

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus, the second duplicate is exactly what I want, but my question, especially the title, is much better than that one, don't you think so? What is the best title?

Comment: Well, I tend to agree with you. I would probably use something like "Build lambda expression (predicate) with dynamic comparison operators". But that's a detail. You may change the other post title, maybe...

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus, done as you recommended, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If conditionals inside your lambda look unsightly to you, you can use a function

```
Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> exp= em => foo(em, otherParam);

public static bool foo(Employee em, otherType otherParam)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not understand, sorry, how does it run with ExpressionType?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that has a `Func<Employee, bool>` and overrides the `ToString` method to represent the operator that the function is using. Then, I would use an `ObservableCollection` of that class as the `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBox`.

Call your class `Operator`, and your code to perform the operation becomes:

```
var op = dropDown.SelectedItem as Operator;

if (op != null)
{
  op.Function(employee);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain type of "Operator"? I my case, it's ExpressionType.